# How to resolve the appearance of span in mobile phone when using Moodle App

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile, moodle-theme

When you view a quiz in the moodle mobile app, the  line of code appears with class sr-only in span. How to resolve it in Moodle 4.1 ?

[Click to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTtLI.jpg)

The page display well in web browser. I have tried to figure out which page results to that error without any successful

Comment: That’s not an error, ‘sr-only’ is a commonly used class to target screen readers (Note the text inside). As its a CSS class, you can target the span with: .sr-only

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message **in text form**, the code involved, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in the 4.2 release, you can look at the details here: [MOBILE-4289](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MOBILE-4289)